# Differentiation using First Principle

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How to differentiate $(\sin x)^{\cos x}$using the first principle of differentiation? Could someone please help me evaluate the limit?

I tried using $e^{\cos x \ln\sin x}$ but couldn't simplify the limit further. Thanks in advance.

P.S.
This isn't a homework problem, it emerged from an after class discussion today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non - logarithmically:
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\sin (x+h))^{\cos (x+h)} - (\sin x)^{\cos x}}{h}
 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\sin (x+h))^{\cos (x+h)} - (\sin (x+h))^{\cos(x)} + (\sin (x+h))^{\cos(x)}-(\sin x)^{\cos x}}{x} 
=\lim_{h \to 0}(\sin (x+h))^{\cos x} \frac{e^{\delta\cos x.log_e\sin x}}{h} + \frac {(\sin x)^{\cos x} + \cos x (\sin x)^{\cos x -1}\delta\sin x + \dots}{h}
=(\sin x)^{\cos x} \bigg(-\sin x.log_e\sin x + \cot x \csc x \bigg)$

Logarithmically:

$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{\cos(x+h)log_e(x+h)} - e^{\cos xlog_e\sin x}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} e^{\cos x.log_e\sin x} \frac{e^{\delta\lambda}-1}{h}
where, \lambda = \cos x.log_e\sin x.
$ 
$= \lim_{h \to 0}(\sin x)^{\cos x}\bigg(-\sin x. log_e\sin x + \cos x .\big(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\big)\bigg)$ or $(\sin x)^{\cos x}\bigg(\cos x \cot x - \sin x. log_e \sin x \bigg)$

Comment: What is delta in the exponent of e?

Comment: Delta stands for change in a quantity. Here it stands for change in $\cos x.log_e\sin x$

Comment: Sorry @DhawalPatil I phrased my question strangely in the deleted post, I posted without reading the content. I realise now they are very different approaches but still answer the same question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it though. Gave me the idea to merge them.